# Accessible tools for prototyping?

Tags: accessibility, applications

I'm a visually impaired beginner on UX Design. Are there accessible tools for prototyping? I'd love to learn more about UX Design and Voice UI as I'd love to create my own voice UI.

Answer (score 3):

Lo-fi protyping is a way to test out ideas quickly. You could start prototyping voice UI converations by drafting scripts and then acting them out through roleplaying. You could then even record the speech as audio and build a lo-fi prototype from this. This was a technique used at [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/info/2018/nov/29/prototyping-voice-apps-through-roleplay)

Secondly, you could practice [Inclusive Design](https://www.microsoft.com/design/inclusive/) and adopt a screen-reader-first approach, using [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/), Apple VoiceOver or Orca for example, to test Information Architectures that are easily navigable by audible user feedback. There are resources availible online for learning more about designing for screen reader compatibility, for example [WebAim](https://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/)

Once you are ready to take your lo-fi prototype to a more refined stage, there are multiple online options springing up for prototyping conversational experiences, such as [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/support#contact-us). I suggest that you review each tool with a screen reader and then go with the tool(s) that has best community support & support for screen-readers. In the near future, there may be a lot of changes in the Voice UI prototyping tool landscape as it is an emerging space, so be sure to check around every once in a while to see if there are now better options available. If you run into problems, don't be afraid to get in contact with them via support and let them know what issues you are running up against.